# Angular 9 - mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl

Tags: angular, ionic, angular-material

Encontrei alguns posts na internet falando sobre este assunto, porém não achei solução para o meu caso.

Tenho um form e quando inicio o APP recebo a mensagem -> mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.

As soluções apontavam para a inserção do matInput no input, mesmo com o matInput a falha continua ocorrendo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

app.module.ts

```
...
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot({
      rippleEffect: true,
      backButtonIcon: 'chevron-back-outline'
    }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    ComponentsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

channe-page.ts

```
import { Component, Input, Injectable, OnInit, LOCALE_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-channel',
  templateUrl: './channel.page.html',
})

export class ChannelPage implements OnInit {

  ChannelCreateForm = this._FormBuilder.group({
    ChannelTitle: [''],
    ChannelDescription: [''],
    ChannelVisibility: [''],
    ChannelEmailPrivateChannel: [''],
  });

  constructor(
    public _FormBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) { }
....
}
```

Meu formulário

```
<form [formGroup]="ChannelCreateForm" (ngSubmit)="CreateChannel()">

    <mat-form-field class="input-full-width" appearance="standard">
      <mat-label>{{'channel.NewChannelPage.name' | transloco}}</mat-label>
      <input matInput #channeltitle type="text" formControlName="ChannelTitle" maxlength="50" />
      <mat-hint align="end">{{channeltitle.value.length}} / 50</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>  

<mat-form-field class="input-full-width" appearance="standard">
      <mat-label>{{'channel.NewChannelPage.description' | transloco}}</mat-label>
      <textarea matInput #channeldescription type="text" formControlName="ChannelDescription" rows="3" maxlength="255"></textarea>
      <mat-hint align="end">{{channeldescription.value.length}} / 255</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
....
</form>
```

Comment: Veja se o erro some adicionando `MatFormFieldModule` à sua lista de imports do módulo.

Comment: Inclui o MatFormFieldModule dentro do app.module.ts e a falha continua. O MatFormFieldModule também dentro do componente.

Comment: Um erro meu, no formulário tenho um mat-radio-button, e como é a primeira fez que crio form com material design, peguei exemplo da internet e este estava dentro de um mat-form-field. Removi o mat-form-field e funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

parte do formulário que tenho um mat-radio-button, estava envolto com um mat-form-field, após remover o formulário funcionou.

```
<mat-radio-group class="radio-group" aria-labelledby="RadioChannelVisibility" formControlName="ChannelVisibility">
  <mat-radio-button class="radio-button" value="public">
    <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="lock_open">lock_open</mat-icon>
    {{'channel.NewChannelPage.public' | transloco}}
  </mat-radio-button>

  <mat-radio-button class="radio-button" value="private">
    <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="lock">lock</mat-icon>
    {{'channel.NewChannelPage.private' | transloco}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa importar o módulo: `MatFormFieldModule`, conforme a [documentação](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api) cita.

```
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
```

Verifique se seu componente está declarado no mesmo módulo que você importou o módulo da material, em `declarations`.

Comment: Adicionei MatFormFieldModule dentro do app.module.ts, mas a falha persiste.